# git fetch upstream is not allowing my public key on windows

Tags: git, webstorm, public-key, github-for-windows

I connected git4windows to my github account and my keys were added to my account. I also see a new key in my .ssh folder. I can push to my repo on github fine from webstorm too.

however I want to rebase of the upstream branch I forked and so I followed this:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/keeping-a-github-fork-updated

However when I try

```
git fetch upstream
```

I get

```
A:\foo>git fetch upstream                                      
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

the exact same method worked find on my linux box. Any ideas?

```
git remote -v                  
origin  https://github.com/foo/bar.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/foo/bar.git (push)
upstream        git@github.com:you/bar.git (fetch)
upstream        git@github.com:you/bar.git (push)
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `git remote -v`? Eventually filtering anything you don't want to share.

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas yes sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your repository is named `foo/bar` and the upstream repository is named `you/bar`.

If you are `foo` but aren't `you`, you will need `you` to give you access to the `bar` repository.

You probably need to use `https` instead of `SSH` to fetch the contents of the `upstream` repository.